# implementing authentication using oauth 2.0 and wicket

Tags: wicket, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

I try to bring up secure communication with our customer using oauth 2.0.
first of all I have to confess that I am totally new to oauth.
Used technologies are as follow: wicket, spring,
I took the following steps.

1. Add dependency in pom.xml

   <dependency>

   <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>

   <artifactId>spring-security-oauth</artifactId>

   <version>1.0.0.M3</version>

   </dependency>
2. Then I added the following in WEB-INF/web.xml

   <filter>

   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>

   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>

   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>

   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>

   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

   </filter-mapping>
3. Finally I added these lines to META-INF/spring-context/application.xml

   <beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryOAuth2ProviderTokenServices">

   <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />

   </beans:bean>

   <oauth:provider client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">

   <oauth:verification-code user-approval-page="/oauth/confirm_access" />

   </oauth:provider>

   <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

   <oauth:client clientId="foo" authorizedGrantTypes="authorization_code" />

   </oauth:client-details-service>

But I got this error:

```
25 09 12 14:48:11:921:ERROR: [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2002)
...
```

Comment: Normally means a jar problem, you sure the right jar is on the class path?

Comment: this post describes a similar setup: http://blog.comsysto.com/2013/05/13/integrating-google-calendar-into-a-wicket-application/

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the spring-core in your maven dependencies. Specifically version 3.1 or upwards.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually like this that when we add a dependency, It contains necessary dependencies itself. Isn't it?
Cause I got so Error and I add till now many dependency but still face some new ones?
Is that logical ... to add dependency till I can run the project. 
I have still no code inside ... just try to add OAUTH dependency!

Comment: Im not too sure what ur asking! Are you asking whether its logical to add dependencies to get the project running even though you have no implementation code?